# How to move category in header panel before Sign In Magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, category, header.panel

Please see the below screenshot. I am trying to move the category menu and want to display HALF TITLE category before sign in header.

[image]

Comment: You can try this with jQuery after window load.

Comment: @RiteshSantra that is not the right nor recommended way to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can not do it by just simply moving a block as a block will contain all the category so you can't move one category out of it. Below is a complete guide on how you can achieve this. (**As just an example, I'm taking 'Training' category from defaults**)

**Point 1.** First, you'll need to **remove the category from the menu** as shown:

[image]

To hide the category from the menu, go to **admin panel > Categories and disable Include in Menu to No**

[image]

**Point 2.** You'll need to add your custom block to the header, for that just create a default.xml to layout in a new module or use any existing module of yours. **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.panel">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Training" name="training" template="Vendor_Module::training.phtml" after="-" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Point 3.** Create a Block as mentioned in the layout which you'll be using to fetch the specific category data which you wish to move to the header. **Vendor/Module/Block/Training.php**

```
    <?php

    namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

    use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

    class Training extends Template
    {
        protected $categoryRepository;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository $categoryRepository,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getCategoryLinks()
        {
            $categoryId = 9; //Parent ID of the Category which you want to move to the header
            $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
            return $category;
        }
    }
```

**Point 4.** Now create a template file mentioned in the layout which will contain the code to list out the category and its subcategories and display it on the screen, **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/training.phtml**

```
    <?php
        $categoryCollection = $this->getCategoryLinks(); //Fetches categories from the Block method $getCategoryLinks
    ?>
    <div style="float:right;">
        <div class="navbar">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <span><a href="<?= $categoryCollection->getUrl(); ?>"><?= $categoryCollection->getName(); ?></a></span>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <?php
                    $subcategories = $categoryCollection->getChildrenCategories();
                    foreach ( $subcategories as $subcategory ) {
                        echo "<a href=".$subcategory->getUrl().">".$subcategory->getName()."</a>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
          </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Point 5.** Create a CSS file that will contain a code to list out the links in a navigation menu style format. **Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css (You can style and display data as per your need.)**

```
.navbar a {
  color: white;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;  
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

**Final output:**

[image]

I Hope, this will help you.